# Transforming a custom React element into its reconciled normal sub-elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I read [this post in the React blog](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html) when describes the component reconciliation process:

> When it sees this element:
>
> ```
> {
>   type: Button,
>   props: {
>     color: 'blue',
>     children: 'OK!'
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> React will ask Button what it renders to. The Button will return this
>   element:
>
> ```
> {
>   type: 'button',
>   props: {
>     className: 'button button-blue',
>     children: {
>       type: 'b',
>       props: {
>         children: 'OK!'
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

My question is, is this functionality directly exposed at all, or otherwise accessible somehow? Like how could I translate that first object into the second one?

---

To preempt questions about why I am asking this...

I am building a sortable table where the individual elements in the table can be strings or React components. If they are strings, sorting is easy. In the case where an element is a React component, I found that I could use [`react-addons-text-content`](https://github.com/rwu823/react-addons-text-content) to extract the text and use that to sort on. That works fine for an element I define like this:

```
const el = <span>Text</span>;
```

But not on one defined like this:

```
const Com = () => <span>Text</span>;
const el = <Com />;
```

For my purposes, I want those to be processed exactly the same, but `react-addons-text-content` can't handle it because of the aforementioned difference between how custom elements and normal elements are represented. If I could transform from the custom element representation to the normal element representation, it would all work.

I am aware that an alternate solution would be to store two values for every element, one for display and one for sorting. But if I can get away without duplicating everything, that seems preferable to me. Suggestions are welcome though, clearly I am not an expert on this stuff :)

Comment: how about call `render()` to get the returned value.

Comment: It'd have to be slightly more complex to handle functional components and nested components, but maybe that could work, I'll have to play around with it later...

Comment: React takes the data you give it, and uses the components you define to generate the DOM. So why not just sort the data that you send to the components? They will render in the order you sort the data.

Comment: Because some of the components are assembling/transforming the data in various different ways, so I'd have to write a bunch of extra functions to duplicate that behavior and then store two copies of all the data (one transformed into React components, one transformed into strings) - seems complicated and likely error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this, because components can be arbitrarily complex and rely on the DOM. So it is potentially an expensive operation. Testing libraries like [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) do provide APIs to do it, but it doesn't really make sense for the use case I was imagining.